# delegate a method with multiple signatures

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

How do I add a method with signature to a thread?

I'm trying to add an item to TreeView GUI using a method `testAdd(DirectoryEntry d, TreeNode t)`

I did it as normal creation of a thread:

```
Thread t1;
t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(testAdd(directory,rootNode));t1.Start();
t1=new Thread(delegate() {testAdd(directory, rootNode);})
t1.start();
```

I get error telling me to use invoke.

How can this be solved?

Comment: You're not supposed to access UI elements from a thread that they weren't created on. If you want to do it anyway, you have to use the `Invoke` method. It has nothing to do with C# really, just with WinForms.

Comment: You cannot directly add items to a treeview with code that runs in a thread.  Controls are not thread-safe.  Use the BackgroundWorker class.

Comment: In case of WPF, you can do the same thing using Dispatcher. Url : http://weblogs.asp.net/pawanmishra/archive/2010/06/06/understanding-dispatcher-in-wpf.aspx

Comment: i need multiple threads and windows forms in my case

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into is that you can't access UI elements from a background thread in a WinForms application.  There is nothing wrong with the signature you're using you're just doing an illegal operation on the UI element.  The actual mutation of the UI element must occur on the UI / Main thread of the application.  A new `Thread` instance guarantees this won't be true.

It's possible to do the work to calculate what you will add on a background thread and then use `Invoke` to get back to the UI thread.  But the actual add must happen on the UI.

Comment: thanks guys, can you give me a sample code of adding node in my case??

Comment: @user1015633 what's wrong with just adding the node directly?